# How to Automate ReactJS Creatable drop-down field with Selenium

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

> I am unable to automate the drop-down field. the dropdown field is a reactjs creatable dropdown where a user can create new value or can select an existing value. And in the HTML snippet starts with . Not the  So we can not use Select Class or Action Class to automate this dropdown field.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-12"><label for="data-provider">Data Provider<span class="red_star">*&nbsp;</span></label></div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="Select data-provider is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
         <div class="Select-control">
            <div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value">
               <div class="Select-placeholder">Enter or Select an existing provider</div>
               <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                  <input id="data-provider" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Avenir; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12"><small class="text-muted">Enter a Data Provider that's not in the list, then hit enter/return</small></div>
   <div class="col-md-12" id="validation-data-provider" style="display: none;"><small style="color: rgb(169, 68, 66);">This field is required</small></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have tried ? And what is the error/exception you got ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a combo box. You can try by sending keys to the required field using any locator.
for example - 
driver.findelement(By.xpath(//div[@role='combobox']).sendKeys("Enter or Select an existing provide").

Please check.

Comment: I have solved how to create value here using sendkeys().                         WebElement we= d.findElement(locatorMap.getLocator("DataProvider"));  
we.sendKeys(dp,Keys.TAB);       But unable to take value from dropdown